# Jasper Reports work fine in Netbeans, no go in JAR

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports

As it says in the title, all my reports work fine if run directly from NetBeans, build my code and all libraries into a JAR and the initial error is

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'sql' language.
```

So I create a file in the src directory 'default.jasperreports.properties' with a mapping to my custom ExecuterFactory

```
net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.SQL=com.mycompany.storage.QueryExecuter
```

This errors with

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.getExtensions(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:247)
```

Further down it reads

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:53)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.createDefaultRegistry(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:81)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.<clinit>(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:69)
```

As if it can't find my custom class. I've also tried putting my custom class in the same package as the class I'm extending and it still doesn't seem to locate it.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: `I've also tried putting my custom class in the same package as the class I'm extending and it still doesn't seem to locate it` - Do you mean the jar with `net.sf.jasperreports` package (*jasperreports.jar*)? Looks like a magic. Did you try to debug with attached source code?

Comment: Yes, that package, was trying to avoid attaching all the source code, what does netbeans have that the JAR doesn't ?

Comment: Did you check the availability of class with classloader?

Comment: yes, it's available

Comment: Maybe another net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.SQL is loaded from classpath.